# How to toggle button in react firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, button

I create a React application with Firebase database, and the concept of the application is an "add to favorite like". More precisely, the user can search an item in a search bar, and add each result to his collection by clicking on button "add to collection". If he want, the user can delete an item from his collection by clicking on "remove to collection" button. Everything work fine !

Everything work fine, but I would like the "add to collection" button to disappear if the user already has the item in his collection, and that is the "remove" button to be displayed. And conversely.

Does someone have an idea ? I try to do this for twi days but no results.

This is my code:

```
function addToCollection(hit) {
  const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const item = hit
  const ref = hit.objectID 

  firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection/${ref}`).update(item);

}

function removeToCollection (hit){
  const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const ref = hit.objectID 

  firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection/${ref}`).remove();
}


const Hit = ({hit}) =>
    <div className="item">
        <img src={hit.avatarURL} width={150} height={150}></img>
        <h1 className="marque">{hit.marque}</h1>
        <h3 className="numero">{hit.numero}</h3>
        <h4 className="reference">{hit.reference}</h4>
        <h4 className="marquesuite">{hit.marquesuite}</h4>
        <p className="cote">{hit.cote}</p>
        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => addToCollection(hit)}>Add to Collection</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => removeToCollection(hit)}>Remove to Collection</button>
    </div>



const Content = () =>
  <div className="text-center">
    <Hits hitComponent={Hit}/>

  </div>






class Catalogue extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { favorited: this.props.isFavorite };
  }


  render(){

    if(this.state.catalogue === null) {
      return  <p>Le catalogue est vide</p>

    }

      return (
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
          <h1 className="text-center">Catalogue de capsule</h1>


          <InstantSearch
            apiKey="b91d4104964a4a28c5f99e41484b09ec"
            appId="ZHUPJYFJTW"
            indexName="catalogue">


            <SearchBox translations={{placeholder:'Rechercher une capsule'}}/>



            <Content />  



          </InstantSearch>

        </div> 

      );
  }
}

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(Catalogue);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
const Hit = ({hit}) =>{
    let itemExists = fasle;
    const itemRef= new Firebase(`users/${userUid}/collection`)
    itemRef.child(hit.objectID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
     itemExists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
     });
    return (<div className="item">
             /*other tags*/
         {itemExists ?
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => removeToCollection(hit)}>Remove to Collection</button> : 
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => addToCollection(hit)}>Add to Collection</button>
          }
    </div>)}
```

Comment: Hello @Amir-Mousavi, thank you for your help. I follow your instruction, but when i launch the app, I have this error message on my screen : "TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__ is not a constructor"

Comment: Well, it seems you just wanted to copy paste an answer and not think a bit yourself and adobt it to your code. This is the approch but if you can not integrate it with a bit change to your program, its your lack of knowledge